# gstreamer remapping microphone audio to rear speakers

Tags: gstreamer

I would like to send audio from my computer microphone to my rear speakers. Microphone and speakers are connected to the same sound card. I have 4 channel setup in Linux Mint. I tried with gstreamer code:

gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audio/x-raw,channels=4 ! audiomixmatrix in-channels=4 out-channels=4 channel-mask=-1 matrix="<<(double)1, (double)0, (double)0, (double)0>, <0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0>>" ! audio/x-raw,channels=4 ! autoaudiosink

It is not working?!
Any idea?
thanks Thomas